# Grails 3.1.16: No Datastore Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here grails

Tags: mongodb, groovy, grails-orm, grails-3.1

I am getting No Datastore Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here grails while calling DomainMappingCached() function. Function returns the class object of DomainMapping where as function inner execution is going correct. I am using GORM 5.0. Below is my code snippet:

```
domainsDel?.each { domainInstance ->
        if (domainInstance.domainMappingCached()) {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with Class.withTransaction{}